# Want to improve image upload speed from my iphone app to my web server based on window

Tags: iphone, ios, photo-upload

I am doing research on speed of photo upload from my iphone application. But I am not able to find out anything over net. I have tried to upload a photo using ASIHttpRequest and also using NSURLConnection.

But I have notice my code takes lots of time to upload a captured photo from camera to my server while facebook does it withing number of seconds about in 20-30 seconds. my code takes about 4 minutes to upload.

I do compress image at client side and then doing upload, but that also take more time then facebook app.

Is there anyone have idea regarding this?

Comment: Can you please place code which you used for image compression.